# How to use distinct keyword on two columns in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11gr2

I used distinct keyword on one column it did work very well but when I add the second column in select query it doesn't work for me as both columns have duplicate values. So I want to not show me the duplicate values in both columns. Is there any proper select query for that.

The sample data is:
For Col001:

```
555
555
7878
7878
89.
```

Col002:

```
43
43
56
56
56
67
67
67
79
79
79.
```

I want these data in this format:
Col001:

```
555
7878
89.
```

Col002:

```
43
56
67
79
```

I tried the following query:

```
Select distinct col001, col002 from tbl1
```

Comment: Please add sample data to your question which explains the problem.

Comment: The query gives you the distinct _combinations_ of col001 and col002. You would have double values in each column, and the other column would have different values then.

Comment: Yes you are right. I have added the sample data as well to explain my requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DISTINCT` works across the entire row considering all values in the row and will remove duplicate values where the entire row is duplicated.

For example, given the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (col001, col002) AS
SELECT 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
--
SELECT 1, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- These are duplicates
SELECT 2, 2 FROM DUAL;
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       col001,
       col002
FROM   table_name
```

Outputs:

> | COL001 | COL002 |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 1 |
> | 1 | 2 |
> | 1 | 3 |
> | 2 | 1 |
> | 2 | 2 |

And the duplicates have been removed.

---

If you want to only display distinct values for each column then you need to consider each column separately and can use something like:

```sql
SELECT c1.col001,
       c2.col002
FROM   ( SELECT DISTINCT
                col001,
                DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY col001) AS rnk
         FROM table_name
       ) c1
       FULL OUTER JOIN
       ( SELECT DISTINCT
                col002,
                DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY col002) AS rnk
         FROM table_name
       ) c2
       ON (c1.rnk = c2.rnk)
```

Which outputs:

> | COL001 | COL002 |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 1 |
> | 2 | 2 |
> | *null* | 3 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=7a06836d6d691695006652e9c475381d)*

Comment: Thank you MTO. I used your last query and solved the problem so if I have tree columns then what could be the query for that.

Answer (score 1):

Use a set operator. UNION will give you the set of unique values from two subqueries.

```
select col001 as unq_col_val 
from your_table
union
select col002 
from your_table;
```

This presumes you're not fussed whether the value comes from COL001 or COL002. If you are fussed, this variant preserves that information:

```
select  'COL001' as source_col
       ,col001 as unq_col_val 
from your_table
union
select 'COL002' as source_col
       ,col002 
from your_table;
```

Note that this result set will contain more rows if the same value exists in both columns.